# Find the missing number in this transformation

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence

I've recently come across this puzzle.

> 2,5,8 = 122348
>
> 3,5,4 = 181224
>
> 7,4,6 = 352230
>
> 5,3,10 = 203340
>
> 3,9,4 = ?

I was able to figure out `30**40` but couldn't proceed further. How are the middle numbers in the right related to the left ones?

Source:

https://brainly.in/question/16666300

https://brainly.in/question/16515827

[image: WhatsApp forward]

Comment: Unfortunately, around here we're sticklers for proper attribution, so I'm going to put this on hold until it contains something more definite than "I've recently come across...". Ideally, a link to where it came from; if at all possible, enough information to enable readers to find the original source for themselves. Thanks!

Comment: @gareth-mccaughan I don't have any source for this. This is a WhatsApp forward. I love solving puzzles and wanted to know the reasoning behind this. I've seen the same question in brainly as well. https://brainly.in/question/16666300  and https://brainly.in/question/16515827. I think they don't count as attributes. But I've seen a lot of questions in this community that fall under my category.  Thanks.

Comment: @duplex143 does all numbers are right ? because i tried many solution one solution is closest . but,for 3,9,4 =33 its giving 34 .

Comment: @Swati I've edited the post to clear any confusion. You're not supposed to deviate from the info already given. But if think the question can be changed, I'm interested to know.

Comment: @duplex143 Sorry im saying about  5,3,10=33 not 3,9,4 . Also, I don't know if the question has some mistake maybe i'm wrong .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Possibly solved? Be the judge yourselves.

Everyone has possibly found the rule that generates the first couple of numbers and the last couple of numbers. The rule is :

> $(a,b,c)\mapsto (d,e,f) \Rightarrow d=a(b+1),\ f=c(b+1)$. Thus $(3,9,4)\mapsto (30,e,40)$. But then, what is the rule that generates $e$ ?

#### <s>Be warned though, the argument that I am going to provide will not work for all triples, but hinges on a very crucial observation provided in the $4$ values given to us, and will only hold for triples following that pattern.</s>

#### Always works now...

We don't need this observation now.

<s>The observation is that:</s>

> <s>$c$ is always even! Once we take the assumption that $c$ will always have to be even, we can proceed.</s>

<s>So far, we have established one assumption</s>

Now we look for patterns.

> <s>We observe that since $c$ is always even, $c/2$ is an integer.</s> Since $e$ has to be a two digit number, call it $XY$ where $X$ and $Y$ represent the digits. There are two observations now. One is that $X+Y=\lfloor(c/2)\rfloor+1$ in all the values that is given. The second is that either $X$ and $Y$ are consecutive with $Y>X$ or $X=Y$. $\lfloor \cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function, which sends any number to the integer just less than it.

How does that help us? Here's how.

> Take $c$, divide it by $2$ and add $1$ to it. Now we have $\lfloor(c/2)\rfloor+1$. Call it $x$. If $x$ is even, divide $x$ by $2$ and set $X=Y=x/2$. Else, set $X=(x-1)/2,\ Y=(x+1)/2$. We check that in the former case $X=Y$ and in the latter case $X<Y$ with $X$ and $Y$ consecutive. Also $X+Y=x$ in both cases, so both our observations hold. And there's a nice symmetry to it!

What does this tell us?

> $(a,b,c)\mapsto (d,X,Y,f)$, a $4$-tuple rather than a $3$-tuple.

Is this true?

> Doing a quick check that our rule works:
> $$(2,5,8)\to \lfloor8/2\rfloor=4\to 4+1=5\to X=(5-1)/2=2,\ Y=(5+1)/2=3\to XY=23$$
> $$(3,5,4)\to \lfloor4/2\rfloor=2\to 2+1=3\to X=(3-1)/2=1,\ Y=(3+1)/2=2\to XY=12$$
> $$(7,4,6)\to \lfloor 6/2\rfloor=3\to 3+1=4\to X=Y=4/2=2\to XY=22$$
> $$(5,3,10)\to \lfloor10/2\rfloor=5\to 5+1=6\to X=Y=6/2=3\to XY=33$$

Finally, the moment has come :

> $$(3,9,4)\to \lfloor4/2\rfloor=2\to 2+1=3\to X=(3-1)/2=1,\ Y=(3+1)/2=2\to XY=12$$

Putting everything together:

> $$(3,9,4)\mapsto (30,12,40) \Rightarrow 3,9,4=301240$$

And that concludes the problem.

> If I am right, I do owe an apology to Galen. He has done such a wonderful job and I would hate to prove him wrong. I wholeheartedly believed he was right, but in the end, I came up with something that does not agree with him. Please accept my humble apologies.

Comment: I'm actually quite happy that you found a human-understandable solution. That's the point of puzzles, which is why I insisted that no one take my answer seriously.

Comment: But as far as I'm concerned, you rose to the occasion against the artificial neural network! Congratulations!

Comment: The rule you inducted is in agreement with my brute-force inference that using only  $*, /, +, -$ is not enough within 7 operations to satisfy all example cases, since you used floor rounding.

Comment: No need to apologize. I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: It is a rant for another place, but these puzzles don't have a unique solution. As long as you find "**a rule**" that satisfies all the examples, and your rule applies to the unknown case (in that the input information for the unknown case is in the domain of your rule/function), then you've made a valid induction. Given a finite number of points, there are an infinite number of sufficiently complicated polynomials that will exactly fit every example point, and yet such polynomials may disagree with each other elsewhere in their images.

Comment: Anyway, as far as the purview of what Puzzling SE is about, your answer is more correct in my view because you used your own mind to reason (and hopefully enjoy) the puzzle. I gave up and used a universal function approximator.

Comment: @Galen Thanks! I did enjoy the puzzle, and I liked your idea of using a neural network to solve this, and I have actually started researching on how neural networks and multiple agent networks can solve such riddles.

Comment: That's fantastic! May it be a rewarding journey of learning for you :)

Answer (score 5):

$3,9,4=$

> $301240$

because

> if we label the inputs $a,b,c$, then the output is $a(b+1):\lfloor\frac{c}{5}\rfloor+1:\lfloor\frac{c}{4}\rfloor+1:(b+1)c$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the 'floor' function, and returns the integer part of its operand.
>
>  The examples:
>  $2,5,8\to 2(5+1:\lfloor\frac{8}{5}\rfloor+1:\lfloor\frac{8}{4}\rfloor+1:(5+1)8=122340$.
>  $3,5,4\to 3(5+1):\lfloor\frac{4}{5}\rfloor+1:\lfloor\frac{4}{4}\rfloor+1:(5+1)4=181224$.
>  $7,4,6\to 7(4+1):\lfloor\frac{6}{5}\rfloor+1:\lfloor\frac{6}{4}\rfloor+1:(4+1)6=352230$.
>  $5,3,10\to 5(3+1):\lfloor\frac{10}{5}\rfloor+1:\lfloor\frac{10}{4}\rfloor+1:(3+1)10=203340$.
>
>  So,
>  $3,9,4\to 3(9+1):\lfloor\frac{4}{5}\rfloor+1:\lfloor\frac{4}{4}\rfloor+1:(9+1)4=301240$.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't upvote** this answer (at least while there's a bounty on the question), and **don't accept** it as an answer. It is a partial answer, and ends with what I hope is a *fun* or *amusing* prediction.

Here's what I figured out by hand:

> For $a,b,c = d,e,f$, I was able to induct that $d = a + ab$ and $f = bc+c$, which has a nice symmetry to it. This suggests, as the OP says, that $3,9,4=30XY40$.

Then I tried:

> A breadth first search of all arrangments ([combinatorics](/questions/tagged/combinatorics)) of $*,/,+,-$ with $a,b,c$ with up to and including 7 operations... amounting to 773514 explored nodes. This didn't result in finding $XY$, suggesting something less obvious than simple arithmetic.

Finally, I tried this (it gets silly here):

> I trained a dense and fully-connected (3,2,3,3,1 for [layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345191/what-is-a-layer-in-a-neural-network) widths) [artificial neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) using [rectified linear units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) for all layers, [stochastic gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) (lr=0.0001), [mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) for [loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function), 1000 epochs, pseudoreplicated data (n=1000), with a [batch size](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network) of 4. The [training](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_sets) [features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_(machine_learning)) were the input triplets, and the training output were the middle column numbers. The final training errors by row were 0.02843285, -0.03020573, 0.02318954, -0.01794052, so the predictions were pretty close ([optimization](/questions/tagged/optimization)); within an integer. If I round round the predictions on the training set to the nearest integer, here are the predictions of the for each case
>  $$ (2, 5, 8) \rightarrow 23 $$
>  $$ (3, 5, 4) \rightarrow  12 $$
>  $$ (7, 4, 6) \rightarrow  22 $$
>  $$ (5, 3, 10) \rightarrow  33 $$
>  So the model learned *some* pattern that approximates the well to the examples because after rounding it didn't get even one of them wrong.
>  General life advice, just because you can train a model like this doesn't mean you should trust what it has to say... Even so, I'll share what it predicted in the next box.

## THE CHALLENGE

> Cue the [boss music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9GaIbECisQ), the [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) predicted that $XY=09$ (well, more specifically $9.006071$). That is to say, the model predicts $ (3, 9, 4) \rightarrow  09$. Defeat the machine by *actually solving this puzzle like you're supposed to*! Go *team humans*!

### Bonus Predictions

> The following tuples were also predicted to map to 09 for the middle digits by the machine learning model.
>  $$(2,3,3)$$
>  $$(2,4,3)$$
>  $$(2,8,4)$$
>  $$(3,5,3)$$
>  $$(3,10,4)$$
>  $$(4,2,2)$$
>  $$(4,6,3)$$
>  $$(4,10,4)$$
>  $$(5,3,2)$$
>  $$(5,7,3)$$
>  $$(5,8,3)$$
>  $$(6,4,2)$$
>  $$(6,5,2)$$
>  $$(6,9,3)$$
>  $$(7,5,2)$$
>  $$(7,6,2)$$
>  $$(7,10,3)$$
>  $$(8,7,2)$$
>  $$(9,8,2)$$
>  $$(10,9,2)$$
>  $$(10,10,2)$$
>  It would be nice to show *all* the predictions, but there are just too many. If there's a specific prediction you'd like to see, put that 3-tuple in the comments of this answer.

Comment: Here's one more added which probably is useful. The middle column numbers are not a linear combination of any 4 of $a,b,c,ab,bc,ca,abc,a^2,b^2,c^2$.

Answer (score -5):

```
2,5,8    122348    2*(8-2)=12      (8+5)+(2*5)=23     (5*8)+8=48

3,5,4    181224    (3*5)+3=18       (3*4)=12       (5*4)+4=24

7,4,6    352230   (6*7)-7=35       (4*7)-6=22       (4*6)+6=30

5,3,10   203340  (3*10)-10=20   (3*10)+3=33    (5*10)-10=40

3,9,4   392133   (4+9)*3=39       (3*4)+9=21      (4*9)-3=33

Your number is 392133.
```

Comment: @Galen.I can not use that symbol.

Comment: galen I never use it before you can tell me how.

Comment: I tried to ″ clean it up″  after you added the ›!, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Can you edit it to further explain what you think the underlying relationships/rules are?

Comment: @Galen. In this question we are given some facts, namely, one group with three single digit numbers and  one group with six digit numbers. The only way to formulate these six digit numbers is by fragmenting them into three parts. Without fragmentation, regardless of what you do with the three single digit numbers, you will never formulate the six digit numbers using the given facts.

Comment: Please explain your answer *within* your answer by editing it. Take us through how you fragmented the number (and define what that means), and how you came up with each equation.

Comment: Everything you ask for is already contained in my answer. Please look again. The only number with two digits is 10.

Comment: There are only 3 words in your answer, which only point to your proposed answer. Use words to explain what you were doing.

Comment: Your answer to a puzzle should not itself be a puzzle; I don't understand all of your equations.

Comment: Why is it only $3  \ \times \ 4 \ + 9 = 21$ and not $3  \ \times \ 9 +4 = 31$  or any other such combo ?

Comment: @Αdvil Sell. It is 21 because in the 6 digit number  392133, when we take two numbers at a time we have 39, 21, 33. None of the other  six digit numbers contains a pair 21, only the one I am showing you here.

Comment: The numbers 39, 21, 33 are divisible by  3 and the result of the divisions are prime numbers  39/3=13,  21/3=7, 33/3=11. In addition,  13-7=6,  11-7=4.  From these results we formulate the sequence 3,6,9  and 4 is one of the given numbers 3,9,4.